# How to make this linking making script behave with markdown?

Tags: php, regex, hyperlink, markdown

I'm using PHP markdown but I also need a script to convert plaintext links into clicakable ones. Both work independently, but when I try to run them together, if I run markdown first, the makelinks still processes on the html code and screws things up.. and.. vice versa. Any idea of how to stop it from doing that? I can't figure out regex to ignore the markdown style links

```
function makeLinks($text) {
    $text = preg_replace('%(((f|ht){1}tp://)[-a-zA-^Z0-9@:\%_\+.~#?&//=]+)%i',
    '<a href="\\1">\\1</a>', $text);
    $text = preg_replace('%([[:space:]()[{}])(www.[-a-zA-Z0-9@:\%_\+.~#?&//=]+)%i',
    '\\1<a href="http://\\2">\\2</a>', $text);

        return $text;
}
```

sample text:

```
###[Title Section](http://domain/folder/page.html)
- Blah blah some text and then a link: www.webpage.org.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double-linkify problem can be solved best with guesswork and workarounds. (We have some duplicate questions, but I can never find a good one..)

Since already converted `http://`-urls only occur right after `href="` or an `>`, you can use those for negative assertions.

```
(?<!href="|>)
```

Should be written at the start of your first regex:

```
$text = preg_replace('%(?<!href="|>)(((f|ht){1}tp://)...
```

Your second regex uses the :space: as anchor, so should be fault tolerant already.

Comment: brilliant! it is (appearing to be) working perfectly. thank you.